# Evaluating an XPath query excluding xml tag

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to know if, using XPath in java, I can obtain a fragment of XML in result of a query. I'll explain better, I'm working oh this simple XML file:

```
<bookshelf>
    <shelf>
        <book>
            <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
            <title>The Lord of the Rings</title>
        </book>
    </shelf>
</bookshelf>
```

The query XPath I have to evaluate is: `/bookshelf/shelf/book`.

I need to find a way to keep the XML tag in the XPATH response getting a result like the following:

```
<author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
<title>The Lord of the Rings</title>
```

Is possible to do that?

Comment: Just search for `/bookshelf/shelf/book/*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using the standard java XPath API:

```
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/bookshelf/shelf/book/*", 
                new InputSource(Snippet.class.getResourceAsStream("/books.xml")),
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("First  node: " + nodes.item(0));
        System.out.println("Second node: " + nodes.item(1));
    }
}
```

You can ask the XPath API to return a list of nodes, a single node, a string, etc. Use the last argument to the `evaluate` method for this: see `XPathConstants` class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, one more thing: How can i add the nodes i get in the evaluation in a List<String>?